# How can I display a string and change to the next string (in the list) using a button?

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that displays strings the goes to the next one using a next button. But my method does not display the string at all. Do I need to use the `setText` method?

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/fact"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="246dp"
    android:text=" "
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header" />
```

Activity Code

```
public class FunFactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button back;
    Button next;
    TextView fact;
    private List<String> listOfFacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun_facts);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fact = findViewById(R.id.fact);
        back = findViewById(R.id.back);
        next = findViewById(R.id.next);
        listOfFacts = new ArrayList<>();

        //adds facts to the listOfFacts.
        for (int i = 0; i < new Database().facts.length; i++) {
            listOfFacts.add(new Database().facts[i]);
        }
        final String firstFact = listOfFacts.get(0);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String nextFact;
                nextFact = firstFact+1;
                displayFact(nextFact);
            }
        });
    }
    public String displayFact(String fact){
        return fact;
    }// display all of the facts one at a time, in order, go to the next one using the "next" button.

}
```

Comment: Why does `displayFact` needs to return a `String` ?  It can be as `public void displayFact(String fact){
     this.fact.setText(fact); 
}`

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
public String displayFact(String fact){
    return fact; 
}
```

Change to:

```
public void displayFact(String fact){
    this.fact.setText(fact); 
}
```

Also, declare a counter as member of the class to keep track of your facts:

```
private int counter;

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    counter = 0;

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter += 1
            String nextFact = listOfFacts.get(counter);
            displayFact(nextFact);
        }
    });
```